# Constantly (but randomly) getting synchronization errors when accessing ChartData.Workbook

Tags: excel, vba, powerpoint

I'm writing a PowerPoint macro to update chart labels. Even though I found a correct algorithm and implemented it I still get two errors when accessing `ChartData.Workbook`. Code:

```
Public Sub EnterNewChLabsNumsCats( _
  objChartData As ChartData, _
  objCategoriesColl As CategoryCollection, _
  dctExceptions As Dictionary)
  
  Dim objCategory As ChartCategory
  Dim i As Long
  Dim strCategory As String
  
  For i = 1 To objCategoriesColl.Count
  
    Set objCategory = objCategoriesColl(i)
  
    strCategory = objCategory.Name
    
    'strAnyDigit - regex for detecting numbers inside a string
    If strCategory Like strAnyDigit Then
    
      Dim strArrCategory() As String
      'strArrCleaned - function to clean non-printables from the string and divide it into array
      strArrCategory() = strArrCleaned(strCategory, True, False)
      
      If (Not Not strArrCategory()) <> 0 Then
        Dim varI As Variant
        
        For Each varI In strArrCategory()
          'blnInDct - function to detect if a piece of the string is in a dictionary containing expressions not to change
          If varI Like strAnyDigit And Not blnInDct(dctExceptions, CStr(varI)) Then
          
            Dim strBefVarI As String
            strBefVarI = CStr(varI)
          
            Dim strAftVarI As String
            'function to change the piece of the string - precisely a number
            strAftVarI = ChangeFinalNumbersTextStrOnly(CStr(varI))
            
            If strAftVarI <> strBefVarI Then
              'this is where I get run-time error '-1328086627 (b0d7019d)': Method 'Activate' of object 'ChartData' failed
              objChartData.Activate
              
              'should I use Excel.Workbook? PowerPoint.ChartData.Workbook doesn't exist
              Dim objChWkbk As Workbook
              If objChWkbk Is Nothing Then Set objChWkbk = objChartData.Workbook 
              
              Dim objChWksh As Worksheet
              Dim objChWkshRange As Range

              With objChWkbk
                'this is where I get run-time error '462': The remote server machine does not exist or is unavailable
                .Application.WindowState = xlMinimized
                .Application.ScreenUpdating = False
                If objChWksh Is Nothing Then Set objChWksh = objChWkbk.Worksheets(1)
                If objChWkshRange Is Nothing Then Set objChWkshRange = objChWksh.Cells
                objChWkshRange.Replace strBefVarI, strAftVarI, xlPart, MatchCase:=False
                .Close savechanges:=True
              End With
              
            End If
            
          End If
          
        Next varI
        
      End If
      
    End If
  
  Next i
  
  'opening ChartData.Workbook again because sometimes changes are not visible on a slide
  Call UpdateCharts(objChartData)
  
  If Not objChWkbk Is Nothing Then objChWkbk.Close savechanges:=True

  Set objCategory = Nothing
  Set objChWkshRange = Nothing
  Set objChWksh = Nothing
  Set objChWkbk = Nothing
  
End Sub
```

Interestingly, I get this errors totally randomly - there's no rule when it happens because often this code works smoothly. What possibly causes these problems and how to avoid them?* Is it an effect of a turned on 'Microsoft Excel 16.0 Object Library' (which I need in this macro)?

*I managed to do this using booleans and `Do-Loop While` structure but I doubt it's the only way.

Comment: Most often, random errors indicate a timing problem. In this case, I would suspect that there is a delay in Excel opening in the background to edit the chart data. Alternatives to a Do loop could be using Sleep or DoEvents (lots of instances of how to use both here on Stack Overflow).

Comment: Sleep or DoEvents may help but the problem is much different. Contrary to what MSDN says ([link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/powerpoint.chartdata.activate)) there's no need to Activate ChartData. Changing data directly in workbook suffices.